# Pandas df.equals() returning False on identical dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, equals, dtype

Let `df_1` and `df_2` be:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
   ...: df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6]})
   ...: df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6]})

In [2]: df_1
Out[2]:
   a  b
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
```

We add a row `r` to `df_1`:

```
In [3]: r = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['x'], 'b': ['y']})
   ...: df_1 = df_1.append(r, ignore_index=True)

In [4]: df_1
Out[4]:
   a  b
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
3  x  y
```

We now remove the added row from `df_1` and get the original `df_1` back again:

```
In [5]: df_1 = pd.concat([df_1, r]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)

In [6]: df_1
Out[6]:
   a  b
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6

In [7]: df_2
Out[7]:
   a  b
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
```

While `df_1` and `df_2` are identical, `equals()` returns `False`.

```
In [8]: df_1.equals(df_2)
Out[8]: False
```

Did reseach on SO but could not find a related question.
Am I doing somthing wrong? How to get the correct result in this case?
`(df_1==df_2).all().all()` returns `True` but not suitable for the case where `df_1` and `df_2` have different length.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [**`pandas.testing.assert_frame_equal(df_1, df_2, check_dtype=True)`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.equals.html), which will also check if the dtypes are the same.

(It will pick up in this case that your dtypes changed from int to 'object' (string) when you appended, then deleted, a string row; pandas did not automatically coerce the dtype back down to less expansive dtype.)

```
AssertionError: Attributes of DataFrame.iloc[:, 0] (column name="a") are different

Attribute "dtype" are different
[left]:  object
[right]: int64
```

Comment: This was the most useful response. I had 'int64' vs 'Int64' in the different df's.

Answer (score 10):

This again is a subtle one, well done for spotting it.

```
import pandas as pd
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6]})
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6]})
r = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['x'], 'b': ['y']})
df_1 = df_1.append(r, ignore_index=True)
df_1 = pd.concat([df_1, r]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
df_1.equals(df_2)

from pandas.util.testing import assert_frame_equal
assert_frame_equal(df_1,df_2)
```

Now we can see the issue as the assert fails.

```
AssertionError: Attributes of DataFrame.iloc[:, 0] (column name="a") are different

Attribute "dtype" are different
[left]:  object
[right]: int64
```

as you added strings to integers the integers became objects.  so this is why the equals fails as well..

Comment: Thanks! What is the reason behind it?  How can it be ignored?  `(df_1==df_2).all().all()` returns `True` but not suitable for the case where `df_1` and `df_2` have different length.

Comment: Convert them to the same type then look to see if they are equal.  Usually, I try to keep data only once, but if you are getting another set of data, checking they are the same dtype is a good thing, and making them the same is better.

Comment: `df_1['a'] = df_1['a'].astype(int)`
`df_1['b'] = df_1['b'].astype(int)`
`print(df_1.equals(df_2))`
will give you the answer you are after.

Answer (score 3):

As per [`df.equals`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.equals.html) docs:

> This function allows two Series or DataFrames to be compared against each other to see if they have the same shape and elements. NaNs in the same location are considered equal. The column headers do not need to have the same type, but the **elements within the columns must be the same dtype**.

So, `df.equals` will return `True` only when the elements have same values and the `dtypes` is also same.

When you add and delete the row from `df_1`, the `dtypes` changes from `int` to `object`, hence it returns `False`.

Explanation with your example:

```
In [1028]: df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6]})

In [1029]: df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6]})

 In [1031]: df_1.dtypes
Out[1031]: 
a    int64
b    int64
dtype: object

In [1032]: df_2.dtypes
Out[1032]: 
a    int64
b    int64
dtype: object
```

So, if you see above, `dtypes` of both dfs are same, hence below condition returns `True`:

```
In [1030]: df_1.equals(df_2)
Out[1030]: True
```

Now after you add and remove the row:

```
In [1033]: r = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['x'], 'b': ['y']})

In [1034]: df_1 = df_1.append(r, ignore_index=True)

In [1036]: df_1 = pd.concat([df_1, r]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)

In [1038]: df_1.dtypes
Out[1038]: 
a    object
b    object
dtype: object
```

`dtype` has changed to `object`, hence below condition returns `False`:

```
In [1039]: df_1.equals(df_2)
Out[1039]: False
```

#### If you still want it to return `True`, you need to change the `dtypes` back to `int`:

```
In [1042]: df_1 = df_1.astype(int)
In [1044]: df_1.equals(df_2)
Out[1044]: True
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments of the others, in this case one can do:

```
from pandas.util.testing import assert_frame_equal

identical_df = True
try:
    assert_frame_equal(df_1, df_2, check_dtype=False)
except AssertionError:
    identical_df = False
```